# mysql server Threads reaching a limit of 153

Tags: mysql, multithreading, performance

I need help with performance tuning of my mysql db.

I'm using a Sugarcrm CE on a machine with the below config
Processor: Xeon E5-2630v3 8 core x 2 
RAM: 16 GB DDR4 
Hard disk: SAS 1 TB Raid 
OS: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 
SugarCRM version: 6.5.10 CE 
DB: mysql 
DB size: 5 GB
Database engine: MyISAM

Sometimes the crm application becomes very slow and takes forever to open the pages. I checked some of the server parameters and observed that whenever the mysql Threads goes close to 150 it becomes very slow (please refer to the attachment). The max the threads goes to is 153. I increased the max_connections to 300 but the no. of Threads still do not go over 153 and become really slow when it reaches that limit.

I did a top command and saw that more the load does not exceed 6-7 in my 16 core server. About 50% memory is also available. CPU is available. So my guess is that it has something to do with the Threads.

Seeking advice on how to troubleshoot and fix this issue. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

- Only rarely can you "tune your way out of a performance problem"
- If you have 153 threads doing some slow query, they will be stumbling over each other and take up to 153 times as long as if you had only one thread at a time.  Check `SHOW PROCESSLIST` to see if you have that case.  If so, *decrease* the number of threads coming in from the outside.
- Let's see the slow query.  It may need something as simple as adding a 'composite' index.
- Switch to InnoDB for better concurrency.

Comment: Thanks for the details. I have the below comments:

Comment: Where are "the below comments"?

Comment: Sorry not sure what exactly happened and why my comments did not get published. Anyways, here they are:
1. So you are saying that this will be difficult to tune even if we have a lot of spare resources like CPU, RAM, Hard disk speed etc?

2. Yes, I think you are right about the slow query part. I've enabled the slow query log too and will review those queries more in detail. But as per your comment, how to decrease the number of threads comming from outside? And what exactly do you mean by outside here?

3. Will review this.

Comment: 4. I had switched to InnoDB but that made the accessing data even slower. For example, database backup which used to take about 10 secs did not finish in even 30 mins. So I reverted back to MyISAM. I guess after migrating to InnoDB I need to tune it for the same. 

Another issue I'm facing is that it becomes slow only when there is load. Without load it works absolutely fine. So it's becoming a little difficult for me to do testing on live server. I guess I'll have to figure out a way to simulate the load on the test server.

Comment: 2. use pt-query-digest to summarize the slowlog.  4. [Tips on switching to InnoDB](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb).

Comment: Thanks Rick. Haven't been able to try this on the live server yet so didn't reply earlier. Will try this tomorrow and get back to you on this.

PS: Nice article :)

Comment: Rick I just tried your recommendation to move to InnoDB. Since the application is Sugarcrm and it handles it's db schema through the application I did not touch the tables directly. I did set innodb_buffer_pool_size and key_buffer_size though. Tried taking a backup and it again takes forever. 20 mins had passed and only 50% of a 5 GB db had been backed up.

Unable to understand how to resolve this.

Comment: Disk drives are not super fast.  20 minutes into 5GB may be reasonable.

Comment: Right. But it was only 50% in 20 mins. So that'd mean it'd take about 40 mins for the entire db. It takes just 2-3 mins with MyISAM.

Comment: 3 minutes for 5GB?  On a spinning disk?  You said RAID, what type of RAID, and how many drives?

Comment: Well...right for testing purpose I'm using a different hard disk which does not have RAID. So it's a SATA drive with 7200 rpm. Also, I just took the backup once again to make sure I didn't make a mistake in saying 3 mins. It took about 1 min 50 secs.